# How to use a contract first approach with GraphQL and Quarkus?

Tags: graphql, quarkus

For REST API I’m using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate java interfaces with jax-rs annotations by an Open API contract and after that, I implement interfaces and run an application at Quarkus with quarkus-resteasy-reactive extension.

Now I want to build GraphQL API at Quarkus using the same approach (generate server code by GraphQL contract). How can I do it with Quarkus with smallrya GraphQL extension (or may be something different)?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Turing85 I have read the policy, and the policy say “Some questions that fit into one of the categories listed above MAY be closed”, it is not a law it is a recommendation. I really have this problem and want to find answer at SO.

Comment: I do not doubt that you have the problem. I cited the [help/on-topic] page; it does not say "*may*", but "*are*", thus it is off-topic as to the guidelines. Rephrasing the question (.e.g "*How can I achieve this by using the MicroProfile standard?*") may resolve the issue.

Comment: @Turing85 the help center say `may`: "Some questions that fit into one of the categories listed above `MAY BE` closed by the community because they aren't generally a good fit here or need additional information:". Your statement it's third item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus implements the MicroProfile GraphQL specification, and that is focused on code-first approach only. For server-side GraphQL development, unfortunately there is currently no tooling for the contract-first approach. Should you be interested in client-side development, there are a few tools... (an experimental generator for typesafe client stubs, and an IntelliJ plugin providing autocompletion of typesafe client interfaces)

Comment: Is it possible for the spring boot?